# BulkInsert error using Entity Framework Extensions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-extensions

I'm trying to get to the root of an issue when using BulkInsert with Entity Framework Extensions but am having no luck.

The error message is as follows:

```
Some EntitySet has not been mapped: 13
 at (DbModel, SchemaMapping, Schema, Schema)
 at Z.EntityFramework.Extenstions.Core.Infrastructure.DbModel.get()
```

Has anybody come across an error message like this before?

Comment: Maybe they already aware of this issue, or you can report it. https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework-Extensions/issues

Comment: I'm the owner of Entity Framework Extensions. We are not aware of this error (I do not find this error message in our code source). I also recommend that you post this issue on our GitHub and provide us with a runnable example that reproduces it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check 'virtual' tag in your entites.
2. Check your mapping codes.
3. İf you'r usin Guid for your id, make sure the guid data is correct.
4. Compare your entities and database tables.

Comment: Example for Virtual tag = public virtual People People { get; set; } or
        public virtual ICollection<ServiceReciept> AgcServiceReciepts { get; set; }(add AgcServiceReciepts = new HashSet<ServiceReciept>(); in your ctor)